Unable to receive DurableClient in dotnet-isolated Function For Durable Entity Processing
In a .NET 8.0 Azure Function V4, I am unable to acquire a valid instance of an IDurableClient. Why?
[Function("ProcessFunction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> 
    Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req, 
        [DurableClient] IDurableClient context)
{
    var mycontext = context; // Null
    // ...
}

Adding in a call to services.AddDurableClientFactory(); has no effect.

CSProject
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>FunctionApp.Durable.Isolated._2</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
...

Package References
"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />

"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.1" />
"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />


"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.4" />
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.13.4" />
"Microsoft.DurableTask.Client" Version="1.2.4" />


https://i.imgur.com/1Em8ICd.png it is only available for .net6 and .net standard 2.0

In .net 8 Isolated one needs to use DurableTaskClient to get the Durable Client. To avoid namespace collisions with the non Isolated attribute, use the isolated specific package of Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.
Below is the code which worked for me:
Function1.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;

namespace FunctionApp184
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> ri_log;
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            ri_log = logger;
        }
        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> 
           Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData       
             , [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient rc)
        {
            ri_log.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, the function started");
            var rith_out = rc;
            ri_log.LogInformation($"The Client is : {rith_out}");
            return new OkObjectResult(rith_out);
        }
    }
}

My packages in csproj:
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DurableTask.Client" Version="1.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
</ItemGroup>

Output:


I don't believe that the example's nuget packages above are up-to-date. (?) I am getting this conflict error and, in the example above there is not a using to specify which one to source: 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableClientAttribute' and 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.DurableClientAttribute'

CS0104 'DurableClient' is an ambiguous reference between ^^^^

That is my compete code and csproj packages and with that it worked for me, try to create a new project and use it. It has worked for me, you can see in screen shots. Please use my code completely. 1,2,3

If I remove Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask and use the targeted to Isolated task, Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask. My compile issue resolves and I do get a non-null DurableClient.
